# General solutions of the equation $ f(x+h,y+h)-f(x+h,y)-f(x,y+h)+f(x,y)=0$

Tags: analysis

What is a general solution of the equation
$$
f(x+h,y+h)-f(x+h,y)-f(x,y+h)+f(x,y)=0 \textrm{ for } x,y \in \mathbb R, h>0,
$$
with unknown function $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Functions of the form $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$  are solutions. Are there another ones?

Thanks

Comment: Does equality hold only for particular $h > 0$ or for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are periodic with period $h$, then another solution is
\begin{align}
f(x,y) = a(x)b(y).
\end{align}

Comment: Seems that your solution can be generalized taking any double-periodic function, i.e. invariant under all shifts in $(h\vec{e_1}, h\vec{e_2})$ lattice, $\vec{e_1} = (1, 0)$, $\vec{e_2} = (0, 1)$.